# tab key focus next empty input in a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

What I'm trying to achieve is that when tab key is pressed, the cursor will be focused on the next empty input in a grid component. Input field that has value will be skipped. If the cursor currently is in input field 2, and input field 3 has value, when tab is pressed, the cursor will jump to input field 4. This is to speed up the form entry time.

Below is the html grid component that I have created

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="dcNonRetainValue">
<fieldset class="ES-border frame-height-collapsed">
    <legend class="ES-border">{{ 'Data Collection' }} </legend>
    <collect-paged-data data="ui.dataCollectionItems" currentPage="ui.dataCollectionItemsCurrentPage" pageSize="ui.dataCollectionPageSize">
    </collect-paged-data>
</fieldset>
```

Trying to focus next input element with js.

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('#dcNonRetainValue *:input:empty').focus();
}, 50);
```

It does not seem to work correctly. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Please check my code work for you?

Comment: Please check again I have Improved the Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` function to select all the empty inputs. Then use `eq` function to select first input and use `focus` function. You can do like below Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input').on( 'keydown', function( e ) {
    if( e.keyCode == 9 ) {
    
      const allEmptyInput = $('input').filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() === ""; 
      });
      
      // Return if there is no Empty Input      
      if (allEmptyInput.length === 0) return;
    
      e.preventDefault();

      const currentInput = $(e.target);

      const nextAllEmptyInput = currentInput.nextAll('input').filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() === ""; 
      });
      
      // Focus on first input if last is focus
      if (nextAllEmptyInput.length === 0) {
        allEmptyInput.eq(0).focus();
        return;
      }

      const firstEmptyInput = nextAllEmptyInput.eq(0);
      firstEmptyInput.focus();

     }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>First Input</label><br/>
<input type="text"/>
<br/>
<label>Second Input</label><br/>
<input type="text"/>
<br/>
<label>Third Input</label><br/>
<input type="text"/>
```

Comment: Tried it. if the cursor currently in input field 1 which is empty, when tab, cursor will always remain on input field 1. what if I want the cursor to jump to input field 3, given that input field 2 is not empty. each tab cursor will keep on going to next empty input field and skip the non-empty one.

Comment: @endlesscalm Please check again I have Improved the Code.

Comment: your solution so far is working well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using `id` will only give you the first element with that `id`. Use `class` instead.